# SQL help extracting data from one table and based on a backup table, inserting that data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL (SSMS) statement that returns invalid records for endstrands not found in the fiberstrands tabl:

```
SELECT * FROM FIBERSPLICE fs
WHERE ENDSTRAND NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM FIBERSTRAND ft)
```

Every record returned here needs to be rectified and placed back into the fiberstrand table based off a backup of the fiberstrand table.

Now, I have a backup table, FiberStrandHAS, that has all of the fiberstrand records that are missing (plus more) as indicated by the above statement.  My goal is to insert the specified records from the above statement using the FiberStranHAS backup table into the fiberstrand table. Any ideas on how I could accomplish this task?

Comment: Can you post your input table structures and desired o/p sample.

Comment: FiberStrand and FiberStrandHAS have the same structures and FiberSplice.EndStrand = FiberStrand.ID.  I just need to take the EndStrand IDs from the FiberSplice table returned from the select statement and only insert those records from FiberStrandHAS into FiberStrand

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out what I needed to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out how to get what I needed...

```
select * 
from fiberstrandhas fsh
inner join (SELECT * FROM FIBERSPLICE fs WHERE ENDSTRAND NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM FIBERSTRAND ft)) es
on (fsh.id = es.endstrand)
```